# Can't execute a .jar packaged application

Tags: java, macos, jar

I'm having troubles with my jar files here. I'm kind of a beginner in Java and I wanted to make a .jar file in order to share my little first program with a friend of mine.
It's a 2 classes program, they depend on each other and work together when compiling and running. I created a MANIFEST.MF file and created a .jar using the command line.

All seem to work, when I type: `java -jar myApp.jar` it works. But when I double-click my myApp.jar file, I expect a terminal window to open and print out some things and nothing happens...

(I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite)

Comment: it doesn't have to open terminal window, unless you are explicitly from your Java code opening it, check what program it tries to open with

Comment: @JigarJoshi How do I check that? I thought using System.out.println("Hello"); would be enough to open a terminal window that prints Hello, isn't it so?

Comment: try to change your code that writes a file, and execute it to validate

Comment: @JigarJoshi I may have misunderstood what you meant: I can't find how to get the program it tries to open with

Comment: I suspect that your program gets executed but since it is just printing on console, you don't see any effect, so I am asking you to create a file when your program runs, to verify this thing

Comment: @JigarJoshi Oh. Then yes it runs and successfully creates a file

Comment: Yes, but still it doesn't open the console when I want to print something. I use `System.out.println("foobar");` and I don't understand where it prints that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544690/java-mac-windows-with-system-out-println

Comment: I thought it would be logged into the terminal. That's why I couldn't see anything. Thanks for your help